# Multiple left outer join With Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have three collection A,B,C
A and B have some what same key names. but cannot merge them into a single collection due to logical separation.
the duplicate key in B needs to be rename into "testlinks" with its value replaced with the mapped document of collection C.
collection A

```
[
  {
    "_id": objectID("asd123"),
    "loc": "blr",
    "date": "2020-01-01",
    "test":{
      "a": true,
      "b": true,
      "c": true
    }
  }
]
```

collection B

```
[
  {
    "_id": objectID("asd999"),
    "loc": "blr",
    "date": "2020-01-01",
    "test":{
      "a": [1,3],
      "b": [6],
      "c": []
    }
  }
]
```

collection C

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/",
    "name": "Rahul",
    "age": 24
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/",
    "name": "sita",
    "age": 26
  }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
  "_id": objectID("asd123"),
  "loc": "blr",
  "date": "2020-01-01",
  "test": {
    "a": true,
    "b": true,
    "c": true
  },
  "testlinks": {
    "a": [
      {
        "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/",
        "name: "rahul"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/",
        "name": "puspa"
      }
    ],
    "b": [
      {
        "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/",
        "name": "ram"
      }
    ],
    "c": []
  }
}
]
```

**For better understanding of requriment** added after matthPen Ans.

1. Match is based on both "date" and "loc".
2. The "_id","loc" and "date" of collection B are absent in the output as it is redundant and few more key like "age" of collection C is also absent in the expected output.
3. (extra requirement) can I execute this query on specific range of documents. condition is "date" between a range and a specific "loc"(location).

[use this to play around](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zs4eZZb6ukQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [$lookup with uncorrelated subqueries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) to perform relationship between A and B, and in these subqueries you have to use multiple $lookup stages to establish relationships between B and C.

```
db.A.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "B",
      let: {
        loc: "$loc"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$loc",
                "$$loc"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "C",
            "localField": "test.a",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "test.a"
          }
        },
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "C",
            "localField": "test.b",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "test.b"
          }
        },
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "C",
            "localField": "test.c",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "test.c"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "testlinks"
    }
  }
])
```

[You can test it here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zNT0d28RGrI)

Comment: Thanks, this solves most of the problem but still leaves a few things  like:  `1.` Match is based on both "date" and "loc". `2.` The "_id","loc" and "date" of collection B are absent in the output as it is redundant and few more key like "age" of collection C is also absent in the expected output. `3.` **(extra requirement)** can I execute this query on specific range of documents. condition is "date" between a range and a specific "loc"(location).
[This](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vQEAYPMCdoa) is incorporated with the No. 1 requirement.

Comment: You have now all what you need to achieve exactly what you want. Use a different $match query inside first A-B lookup for requirement 3. Use the first described $llokup syntax  for B-C relationships if you need to exclude some fields.