# Comparing two Collections with a field Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, collections, mongo-shell

I have two collections with 15 millions plus results of ids and I would like to compare the two so that I can return a result set of cola that is not in colb

cola has 14.5 million documents and colb has 15.5 documents:

Example of cola

```
{
    "_id" : "123"
},
{
    "_id" : "45"
}
```

Example of colb

```
{
    "_id" : "123"
},
{
    "_id" : "456"
},
{
    "_id" : "4"
}
```

I would lke he results to be

```
{
    "_id" : "456"
},
.
.
.
{
    "_id" : "4"
}
```

Using $lookup hangs and using distinct errors out at too large 16mb.  I have also used aggregate and $nin but because aggregate is always an object, $nin errors out as it expects an array.

Hangs and never finishes.

```
db.cola.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "colb",
            localField: "ID",
            foreignField: "ID",
            as: "ID_match"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $eq: [ { "$size": "$ID_match" }, 0 ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

cyclic dependency detected

```
var a = db.cola.aggregate({$group: {_id: "$ClaimID"}});
db.cola.find({ID: {$nin: a}})
```

I also wrote a JS loop but looping through 15 million rows is not efficient.

What else are my options?

Answer (score 0):

i think you have same problem like this
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65044370/17123841). you can use $lookup aggregation function to join two table and take some value what you need